# Github Actions aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials with multiple accounts for deploy and state backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-credentials, terraform-cdk

I'm trying to setup a CI pipeline on Github Actions that could support multiple aws accounts.

I have a "dev" account for deploying all the dev infrastructure and an "admin" account in which we manage terraform state (in an S3 bucket) for multiple projects, including this one.

So when deploying with CDKTF I must access with two accounts: one for the aws provider, that will perform the deploy, and another one to access the bucket holding the state.

I created two roles in the two accounts separately as explained [on the aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials repository](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials) and configured the CI like this

```yaml
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials for Dev
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: $AWS_REGION
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.CI_ROLE_ARN_DEV }}
          role-session-name: dev-session

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials for Admin 
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: $AWS_REGION
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.CI_ROLE_ARN_ADMIN }}
          role-session-name: admin-session
```

But when running `cdktf deploy` I get the error `failed to get shared config profile, dev` where `dev` is the name of the profile specified in the AwsProvider like this

```js
        const provider = new AwsProvider(this, 'aws-provider', {
            region: awsRegion,
            profile: 'dev'
        });
```

In fact, when executing `aws sts get-caller-identity` in GH Actions it outputs like it's logged as the admin account, becuse it's the last one I configured.

I don't know how I can tell Github to manage both accounts at the same time.

Keep in mind: when deploying locally, if I login via sso (`aws sso login --profile <profile-name>`) with both profiles, I can deploy everything with no problem at all.

Following another stackoverflow question (that I can't find right now), I tried configuring the profiles like this directly in the CI

```yaml
- name: Configure aws credentials
  run: |
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV }} --profile dev
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }} --profile dev
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_ADMIN }} --profile admin
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ADMIN }} admin
    cat "$AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE"
```

and despite it `cat`ing the right information, when `cdktf deploying` I get the following

```
error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
```

Also when calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` on both profiles i always get
`An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Comment: Are you trying to use AWS SSO within an automated environment, like a CI pipeline? I don't think that's going to work, since AWS SSO is built for humans. You might want to consider creating a scoped down role for your deployment if you're intending to use it from a pipeline.